# Bash script file as input

Tags: linux, shell

i am trying to give an file as input to me my shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
file ="$1"
externalprogram "$file"
echo 'unixcommand file '
```

i am trying to give the path to my file but it says always

> cannot open `=/home/username/documents/file' (No such file or directory)

my path is this /home/username/Documents/file

i do this in terminal : ./myscript.sh /home/username/Documents/file

can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

When you say

`file ="$1"`

with a space after "file", you're running something called `file` with `=$1` as an argument. There probably actually *is* a utility called `file`. If you want to assign `$1` to a *variable* called `file`, you don't need the space:

`file="$1"`

Comment: No "probably" about it; `file` is a [standard utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/file.html).

Comment: It's reasonable to assume that _that_ `file` is the one being invoked here, but it's an assumption. Container-based Linux images may not include `file` or, in fact, any of the 'standard' utilities.

Answer (score 0):

there shouldn't be a space before = in the second line.
file=$1 should be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Check what [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) says about your code:

```
 ^-- SC1068: Don't put spaces around the = in assignments (or
 quote to make it literal).
```

You can read more about SC1068 case on [its Github
page](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1068).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1

code $file

echo "aberto o arquivo ${file} no vscode"
```

I made this code snippet to demonstrate, I pass a path and it opens the file in vscode